# Can't remove docker unnamed volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to remove docker volumes which are dangling or unnamed.

I tried `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)` but I got the following error:

```
"docker volume rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker volume rm --help'.

Usage:  docker volume rm [OPTIONS] VOLUME [VOLUME...]

Remove one or more volumes
```

docker version:
Docker version 24.0.1, build 6802122

Comment: It tells you the volume is in use by a specific ID. What happens if you `docker container inspect` that ID? The container may be stopped (`docker ps -a`).

Comment: Please don't delete your question with an answer and comment on it to repost the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the answer, i jsut had to run the following command:

```
docker system prune --volumes
```

if some unnamed volumes remained just run:

```
docker volume rm <volume_ID>
```